# How to validate an Ethereum address using Joi

Tags: javascript, ethereum, joi

A valid ethereum address is "0x" + 40 hex characters.

What would be the [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) definition to validate that ?

Comment: If I've read the documentation you linked to correctly, my guess is `Joi.string().regex(/^0x[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$/)`

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `.extend` method of joi for creating custom validation. you can have regex based checking in `.extend` method.
reference https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.0.1/API.md#extendextension